# How to validate an email address with two periods in it (Python)

Tags: python, regex, email-validation

Below there's a code snippet where when you input an email address, such as email@gmail.com, it will say it's valid.

However, if I type an email address such as email@students.school.edu, it will say it's invalid. I tried this with my own school email address that has two periods in it, and it said it was invalid.

Is there a way to validate with regex a regular email address with one period AND an email address with two periods in it as shown below?

```
import re
email = input ("Type in an email address: ")
if re.match("\A(?P<name>[\w\-_]+)@(?P<domain>[\w\-_]+).(?P<toplevel>[\w]+)\Z",email,re.IGNORECASE):
    print("Email is valid")
else:
    print("Email is invalid")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the python regex standard for emails:

```
r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)
```

Source: https://emailregex.com/

So, in the context of your original snippet, it would be:

```
import re
email = input ("Type in an email address: ")

if re.match(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)", email):
    print("Email is valid")
else:
    print("Email is invalid")
```

Comment: what do you mean "python regex standard for emails"?  What is the source for this?

Comment: ^^ Not meant as a challenge just genuinely interested on the authority of this statement

Comment: Sure, I dont think it's an 'official' source haha, just what I found when I googled. I updated my answer with the link.

Comment: Note that this will also match `email@students.school...`

Comment: Thank you so much! Was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: `aaa@bbbb.co.uk.` is matching. should be `re.match(r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+[a-zA-Z]$)', email)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
email = input ("Type in an email address: ")
if email!= "":
    mailValidation = bool(re.search("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[comrgin]", email))
    if mailValidation == True:
        print("Validate mail.")
    else:
        print("Please check mail.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to integrate some exteral bit more sophisticated solution, like [mailcheck.co](https://mailcheck.co) or similar service. Main point is that you can do much more than formal check. You can validate is email operational or not, user actual name, profile photo etc.